# Terminal: Use different command on previous file

Tags: command-line, terminal, command-history

I know that there is the `!!` command to reuse the previous command. How would one reuse the file or directory specified in the previous command but use a different command on it?

Example: I want to see what is the content of a file, and if necessary delete it. Something like:

```
$ cat example.txt

"output indicates deletion"

$ rm !!
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo foo
foo
$ bar !!:$
bar foo
The program 'bar' is currently not installed...
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

Comment: Nice one! I read the manual you linked below your answer and suggest you add to your answer that the command can even be shortened to `!$`

Comment: It's past 11 AM but it's even too early in the morning to have a full-fledged brain blood pressure.

Comment: Depends on where you live. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

- `rm` <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> - type `rm` followed by <kbd>Space</kbd> and after press <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>.</kbd> (not in the same time). If the previous command has no arguments, you will get the previous command itself.
- `rm` <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> - type `rm` followed by <kbd>Space</kbd> and after press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>.</kbd> (in the same time). In fact, using this way and continuing to  press <kbd>.</kbd> (without to release <kbd>Alt</kbd>), you will get the last argument for every command from history. If a command has no arguments, you will get the command itself.
- `rm !*` - in this case you will get all arguments from the previuos command.  If the previous command has no arguments, you will get nothing.

In general: `<command>` <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> or `<command>` <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or `<command> !*`.

Source: [Run a command with the argument from the last command](https://askubuntu.com/a/304831/147044).

Answer (score 1):

All of these will accomplish what you want:

```
rm !$
```

The `!$` means the last argument of the last command.

```
rm!:1
```

`!:1` means argument 1 of the last command, where the command itself is argument 0.  You can pick out individual arguments from the last command this way.

```
^cat^rm^
```

Replace the string `cat` with the string `rm` in the last command and run the result.  You can actually leave off the last `^` in this simple case.

```
rm !*
```

This runs `rm` on *all* of the non-command arguments in the last command.  So arguments from 1 to `$`.  This variant and the last one are useful if you had more than one argument to the last command.